# MongoDB & NodeJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Добрый день, только начал изучать Node.JS, поэтому не будьте строги)
Пытаюсь создать приложение с обменом данными с базой MongoDB, но не могу выполнить POST-запрос к базе.

Выпадает ошибка

> TypeError: db.collection is not a function

И почему-то в консоли пишет

> connection accepted from 127.0.0.1:51061 #4 (1 connection now open)

То есть не тот порт.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); 
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var db = null;
app.use(bodyParser.json()); 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.get('/user',function(req, res){ res.send(users);  })

app.post('/user',function(req, res){
    var user = {
        login: req.body.login
    };
    db.collection('users').insert(user, function(err, result){
        if(err){
            console.log(err); 
            return res.sendStatus(500);
        };
        res.send(user);
        db.close();
    })
    res.send(user);
})


MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chat_bd', function(err, database){
    if(err){return console.log(err)}
    db = database;
    app.listen(4040, function(){    //in 4040 port(http://localhost:4040/)
        console.log('All Is OK')
    });
})
```

Версия MongoDB последняя на текущий момент, версия драйвера 3.0.3

Answer (score 0):

У Вас в коде каша. Первое - [єто](http://expressjs.com/ru/guide/database-integration.html#mongo) обязательно к прочтению. Второе как-то так (проверить мне негде, но по идее должно работать):

```js
    var express = require('express');
    var app = express();
    var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
    var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
    app.use(bodyParser.json());
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

    app.get('/user',function(req, res){ res.send(users);  })

    //POST http://localhost:4040/user
    app.post('/user',function(req, res){
        let user = {
            login: req.body.login
        };
        my_connect.db.collection('users').insert(user, function(err, result){
            if(err){
                console.log(err);
                return res.sendStatus(500);
            };
            res.send(user);
            db.close();
        })
        my_connect.res.send(user);
    })

    const my_connect = MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/chat_bd', function(err, database){
        if(err){return console.log(err)}
    })
    //chat_bd єто и есть наша БД поєтому не нужно создавать отдельную переменную БД
    app.listen(4040, function(){    //in 4040 port(http://localhost:4040/)
        console.log('All Is OK')
    });
```

А вообще попробуйте использовать Mongoose для работі с БД Монго на Ноде.